# How to group by server in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

here's the code:

***list.component.ts***

```
 data = [   {
          "id": 19,
          "server": "Server 1",
          "dl": "35.88 Mbit/s",
          "ul": "46.76 Mbit/s",
        },
        {
          "id": 30,
          "server": "Server 1",
          "dl": "45.06 Mbit/s",
          "ul": "48.25 Mbit/s",
        },
        {
          "id": 26,
          "server": "Server 1",
          "dl": "47.96 Mbit/s",
          "ul": "47.89 Mbit/s",
        } ]
```

how to group the `Server 1`?

the output should be

```
{
   server: 'Server 1',
   data: [
{
              "id": 19,
              "dl": "35.88 Mbit/s",
              "ul": "46.76 Mbit/s",
            },
            {
              "id": 30,
              "dl": "45.06 Mbit/s",
              "ul": "48.25 Mbit/s",
            },
            {
              "id": 26,
              "dl": "47.96 Mbit/s",
              "ul": "47.89 Mbit/s",
            }
]
}
```

Comment: post the attempt.

Comment: I think I didn't understand your question. What do you mean by group?

Comment: I don't know why you are not using "lodash" lib like this _.groupBy(data, "server").

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to group by `server` and [Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) syntax to get `other` object fields:

```js
let data = [   {
          "id": 19,
          "server": "Data1",
          "dl": "35.88 Mbit/s",
          "ul": "46.76 Mbit/s",
        },
        {
          "id": 30,
          "server": "Data1",
          "dl": "45.06 Mbit/s",
          "ul": "48.25 Mbit/s",
        },
        {
          "id": 26,
          "server": "Data1",
          "dl": "47.96 Mbit/s",
          "ul": "47.89 Mbit/s",
        } ]
        
 let result = data.reduce((state,current) => {
     let {server, ...others} = current;
     if(state[server]){
         state[server].push(others);
     } else {
         state[server] = [others];
     }
     return state;
 }, {});
 
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also group data using **forEach**.

```
let data = [
  {
    "id": 19,
    "server": "Data1",
    "dl": "35.88 Mbit/s",
    "ul": "46.76 Mbit/s",
  },
  {
    "id": 30,
    "server": "Data1",
    "dl": "45.06 Mbit/s",
    "ul": "48.25 Mbit/s",
  },
  {
    "id": 26,
    "server": "Data1",
    "dl": "47.96 Mbit/s",
    "ul": "47.89 Mbit/s",
  },
  {
    "id": 36,
    "server": "Data2",
    "dl": "41.98 Mbit/s",
    "ul": "41.82 Mbit/s",
  }
];

const groupedArray = (arr) => {
  let newArray = {};
  data.forEach(obj => {
    if(newArray[obj['server']] == undefined){
      newArray[obj['server']] = [ obj ];
    } else{
      newArray[obj['server']].push(obj);
    }
  });
  return newArray;
}

let newData = groupedArray(data);
console.log(newData);
```